# Background Script is not sending message to document script - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am working with chrome extension and trying to send a message from background script to the content script. But I do not know why the message from background is not passing to the content script.

> First of all I check the cookies in the background script, if the cookies are available then it passes a message  `{type:"allow_access"}` if no cookies are available then it passes `{type:"not_logged_in"}`. This object has been passed to the content scripts, and the `switch(sent.type)` decide about what has been passed to the content script. And after that a function had been called in the first case and in the other case only `alert()` method.
>
> > But Unfortunately there might be some problem with my code that is preventing that message from passing to the content script.

**Note** - The `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"open_login"});` in the very beginning is simply sending a message to background script to open a tab. And is a separate message.

**Document Script**

```js
var bact_btn = document.getElementById("openLogin");
bact_btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"open_login"});
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(sent,sender,res){
    console.log("Document Script is called  !");
 switch(sent.type){
  case "allow_access":{
      alert("You are logged in !")
      populate();
      break;
     }
     case "not_logged_in":{
      alert("You are not logged in to your account to use the extension ! Please login.");
      break;
     }
 }
 
});

function populate(){
    alert("Populate has been called ! ");
 var fbEl = document.getElementsByClassName("_42nr");
 var fbPost = document.getElementsByClassName("_5jmm _5pat _3lb4 s_1qgkos469b");
 var fbPostUrl = document.getElementsByClassName("_5pb8 _8o _8s lfloat _ohe");
 var h = '<a href="" ><div style="float:left;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;height:14px;color:#4b4f56;" class="myprivateLikeButton"><img src="http://bitbaysolutions.com/Icons/icon_like.png" style="width:17px;height:17px;margin-right:7px;float:left;margin-top:-4px;">Private Like</div></a>';
 var currCont = 0;

 window.onload = function(){
     currCont = fbPost.length;
     console.log(currCont);
 }


 for (var i = 0; i < fbEl.length ; i++) {
  if((fbEl[i].children.length<=3) && !(fbEl[i].children[0].innerText.toLowerCase().trim()=="private like")){
   fbEl[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',h);
  }
 }

 window.onscroll = function(){
  if(fbPost.length>currCont){
   for (var i = 0; i < fbEl.length ; i++) {
    if((fbEl[i].children.length<=3) && !(fbEl[i].children[0].innerText.toLowerCase().trim()=="private like")){
     fbEl[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',h);
    }
   }
  }
 }

 document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var ev = e.target; 
  if(ev.innerText=="Private Like"){

   var liked = "http://bitbaysolutions.com/Icons/icon_liked.png";
   ev.firstChild.setAttribute("src",liked) ;
   ev.style.color="#e20505";

   getIndex(fbEl,ev.parentElement.parentElement);

  };
 });
 function getIndex(el,pr){

  //Find the index value of the fb Element clicked
  var index=-1;
  for(var i=0;i<el.length;i++){
      if(el[i]===pr){
           index=i;
           break;
      }
  }
  getUrl(index);
 }

 function getUrl(ind){
    var postInd = -1;
    for(var i=0;i<fbPost.length;i++){
      if(i==ind){
       postInd=i;
         var url = fbPost[postInd].getElementsByClassName("_5pb8 _8o _8s lfloat _ohe")[0].getAttribute("href");
         chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"postUrl",mess:url});
      }
    }
 }


}
```

**Background Script**

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
   
   if (document.cookie.indexOf("_session") >= 0) {

        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){ 
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type:"allow_access"}, function(response) {
       
      }); 
     });
       
 } else{ 
  
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){ 
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type:"not_logged_in"}, function(response) {
       
      }); 
     });
 

 }
});

chrome.tabs.create({url:"myFrame.html"});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(sent,sender,res){

 switch(sent.type){
  case "postUrl":{
   checkUrl(sent.mess);
   break;
  }
  case "open_login":{
   chrome.tabs.create({url:"myFrame.html"});
   break
  }
 }
 
});


function checkUrl(url){
   $.ajax({
      method:"GET",
      url:"http://www.bitbaysolutions.com/connections.php?fbPostUrl=true",
      data:{
       url:url
      },
      success:function(r){
         alert(r);
      }
   });
}
```

**The Manifest**

```js
{
 "name":"My Extension",
 "description":"I am working with my extension yet, Mr. chrome.",
 "version":"1.0",
 "manifest_version":2,
 "icons":{"16":"icons/icon_liked.png","32":"icons/icon_liked.png","64":"icons/icon_liked.png","128":"icons/icon_liked.png"},
 "content_scripts": [
     {
       "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*","http://www.facebook.com/*"],
       "js": ["jquery.js", "document.js"]
     }
    ],

    "background":{
     "scripts":["jquery.js","background.js"]
    },
    "permissions":[
        "cookies",
        "tabs",
     "http://www.facebook.com/*",
        "https://www.facebook.com/*",
        "https://www.fiverr.com/*",
        "http://*/*",
        "http://www.bitbaysolutions.com/"
       
    ],
 "browser_action":{"default_icon":"icons/icon_liked.png","default_popup":"popup.html"}
}
```

Comment: 1. The term is "content script" 2. `$(window).on('load'` is not doing what you probably think it does in the background page (which is a separate hidden page with its own DOM and `window` object) - it's executed just one time during browser startup.

Comment: Still it returns a message which I write console.log or alert something

Comment: It may appear to work just because you're reloading the extension - it runs `on('load'`. Like I said it's not what you want. Have you read [the architecture article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)?

Comment: but, even if I remove it, it doesn't do what I want

Comment: Of course. Instead of removing it you need to place it in the correct place. I guess inside `success` callback function.